# Homebrew vim already installed when brew update displays Vim as a updated formula

Tags: software-update, homebrew

simple questions,

when I run `brew update` here is the result

```
[admin@mb125:~/src/test] : brew update
Updated Homebrew from 16bd5c86 to 24073dc0.
==> New Formulae
mal4s  nbimg
==> Updated Formulae
aws-elasticbeanstalk   boost-bcp          ex-vi          libxml2            vim            youtube-dl
```

Great there is an updated Vim, let's update it.

```
[admin@mb125:~/src/test] : brew upgrade vim
Error: vim-7.4.052 already installed
```

so, how do I see what has been updated for Vim and why I can't upgrade it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Formula updates don't necessarily mean the software which formula installs is updated. So, running `brew upgrade` without other parameters will bring brews which are outdated up to date whereas running `brew upgrade <specific brew>` might produce an error in case it's only the formula and not the brew which has been updated.